# Why is my completion block being triggered with NSOperation object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, concurrency, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have an NSOperation custom class in which I added a method to accept block for easiness such that I could assign the completion block. But, even if I dont call the block, it is being returned to the main calling class and sends message with itself being passed.

**`Interface :`**

```
@class  SKSimpleDownloadOperation;
typedef void(^CompletionBlock)(id Json, NSError *error);
@protocol SKSimpleDownloadDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)operation:(SKSimpleDownloadOperation*)operation didCompleteWithData:(NSData*)data;
-(void)operation:(SKSimpleDownloadOperation*)operation didFailWithError:(NSError*)error;
@end
@interface SKSimpleDownloadOperation : NSOperation
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSInteger statusCode;
-(id)initWithUrlRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request andDelegate:(id<SKSimpleDownloadDelegate>)aDelegate;
-(id)initWithUrlRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request andDelegate:(id<SKSimpleDownloadDelegate>)aDelegate withCompletionBlock:(void(^)(id json, NSError *error))completionBlock;
@end
```

**`Implementation:`**

```
@interface SKSimpleDownloadOperation()<NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSURLRequest *request;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData *data;
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<SKSimpleDownloadDelegate>delegate;
@property(nonatomic, copy) CompletionBlock completionBlock;
@end
@implementation SKSimpleDownloadOperation
@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize request;
@synthesize statusCode;
@synthesize completionBlock;

-(id)initWithUrlRequest:(NSURLRequest *)aRequest andDelegate:(id<SKSimpleDownloadDelegate>)aDelegate withCompletionBlock:(void (^)(id, NSError *))aCompletionBlock{
    if(!(self = [super init])) return nil;
    [self setRequest:aRequest];
    [self setDelegate:aDelegate];
    [self setCompletionBlock:aCompletionBlock];
    return self;
}
-(id)initWithUrlRequest:(NSURLRequest *)aRequest andDelegate:(id<SKSimpleDownloadDelegate>)aDelegate{
    return [self initWithUrlRequest:aRequest andDelegate:aDelegate withCompletionBlock:nil];
}

-(void)main{
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:[self request] delegate:self];
    CFRunLoopRun();
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response{
    [self setStatusCode:[response statusCode]];
    [self setData:[NSMutableData data]];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)newData{
    [[self data] appendData:newData];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    if(self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(operation:didCompleteWithData:)])
    [[self delegate] operation:self didCompleteWithData:[self data]];
    CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
//    if(completionBlock != nil){
//        [self performSelector:@selector(callBlockWithNecessaryParameter) onThread:[NSThread mainThread] withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
//    }
}

-(void)callBlockWithNecessaryParameter{
    NSError *error = nil;
    id object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[self data] options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
    // completionBlock(object,error);
    //completionBlock = nil;

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    [[self delegate] operation:self didFailWithError:error];
    CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
}
@end
```

How I call the operation;

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20item%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20location%3D%2248907%22&format=json"]];
    ViewController __weak *__viewController = self;
    NSOperation *operation = [[SKSimpleDownloadOperation alloc] initWithUrlRequest:request andDelegate:nil withCompletionBlock:^(id json, NSError *error) {
        [__viewController populateReceivedJSON:json];
    }];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [queue addOperation:operation];
    operation = nil;
    queue = nil;

-(void)populateReceivedJSON:(id)json{
    NSLog(@"JSON --> %@", json);
}
```

As you see in the above code I uncommented the call to block in connectionDidFinishLoading: method but the block is being called and the method populateReceivedJSON is being triggered.

And more interesting to me is log shows the same instance of NSOperation subclass as;
**`JSON --> <SKSimpleDownloadOperation: 0x7462be0>`**

I could not understand what is the problem here ? When I call delegate it works fine but the block gets called always. I would like to thankyou in advance for your warm suggestions and ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NSOperation Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html)

> **completionBlock**
>   Returns the block to execute when the operation’s main task is complete.
>
> -(void (^)(void))completionBlock
>     **Return Value**
>   The block to execute after the operation’s main task is completed. This block takes no
>   parameters and has no return value.
>
> **Discussion**   The completion block you provide is executed when the value returned by the isFinished method changes to YES. Thus, **this
>   block is executed by the operation object after the operation’s
>   primary task is finished or cancelled**.

If you place the Operation on a Queue the completion block will be call when the operation is completed or cancelled.
Also your "custom" completion block may be interfering with the "completionBlock" of NSOperation.
`I would suggest using a different name for your custom completionBlock,` since it's not the behaviour of the NSOperation completionBlock that you want, but something else.

Comment: Yes that was the problem. I was using a completionBlock with some parameter in it. But, NSOperationClass already has a property named completionBlock. So, I changed completionBlock to completedBlock and everything works well.